# freetype lib new version is incompatible with old code

Tags: libgdx, freetype, lib

I trying to export and old game made on libgdx to this latest version but I have code erros because i'm using freetype 1.9.6 lib, and this version of freetype dont use comands like **generateFont** , **setScale**,**drawWrapped**,**getBounds** and **getWrappedBounds**, does anyone know how to fix this? is it possible to donwgrade the lib on eclipse or is better to fix the code, how can i install the old  freetype lib version on a gradel project on eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Generate font is there in 1.9.6

```
FreeTypeFontParameter fontParameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
        FreeTypeFontGenerator fontGen = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(
                Gdx.files.internal("font/ROBOTO-REGULAR.TTF"));

        fontParameter.size = 18;
        BitmapFont bitmapFontRegular18 = fontGen.generateFont(fontParameter);
        bitmapFontRegular18.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        fontGen.dispose();
```

For scaling, Use

```
font.getData().setScale(,);
```

Now no need to use drawWrapped method.

You can simply use `font.draw(...)` and \n where you want to have a new line.

http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3658